# Creating repository in bitbucket using c# code

Tags: c#, bitbucket

I want to create repository in bitbucket using rest api using c# code.
[I am using free bibucket account]

```
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}

--url 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
```

This does not works for me.
I provided App token to create repo.

Or is there any way to create repo and push the data into repo using Basic auth?? (username and password).

Code :-

```
private string CreateNewBitbucketRepo(string ownername, string password, string repositoryname)
{
    try
    {

        // Construct the URL for Bitbucket API to create a new repository
        var apiUrl = $"https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{ownername}/{repositoryname}";

        // Create a JSON payload to specify the repository details
        var payload = new
        {
            name = repositoryname,
            is_private = false
        };

        var jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{ownername}:{password}")));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", password);
            var content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                return $"\nE: For some reason, the repository {repositoryname} can't be created on Bitbucket. {response.ReasonPhrase}";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return $"\nSomething went wrong. The repository {repositoryname} can't be created on Bitbucket. {e.Message}";
    }
}
```

I provided correct username and App token in password.

I also tried using username and password ( Basic Auth ) -- did't work.

Comment: How exactly does it not work?

Comment: What is the http response you get? Could you show how you make a request in c# (do you use `HttpClient` for instance)?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution to this question.

First create app token - give necessary permissions.--> [How to create App token in bitbucket?](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/create-an-app-password/)

**Pass username in the username as usual.
Pass App token in Password**
Don't pass you bitbucket account password.

private string CreateNewBitbucketRepo(string ownername, string password, string repositoryname,string username)
`{ try {`

```
    // Construct the URL for Bitbucket API to create a new repository
    var apiUrl = $"https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{ownername}/{repositoryname}";

    // Create a JSON payload to specify the repository details
    var payload = new
    {
        name = repositoryname,
        is_private = false,
    };

    var jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")));

        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", password);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            return $"\nE: For some reason, the repository {repositoryname} can't be created on Bitbucket. {response.ReasonPhrase}";
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return $"\nSomething went wrong. The repository {repositoryname} can't be created on Bitbucket. {e.Message}";
}
```

`}`